# What is a good data mining / BI / report tool for MySQL?

Tags: mysql, data-mining, business-intelligence

I am looking for a tool, service, or framework that would allow us to expose our database to management. I have looked, although briefly, at JasperSoft and Crystal Reports. They looked "OK".

We are not afraid of writing our own queries so long as we can save them somewhere for later use by the business crowd. Ideally, the interface would be web based and reports could be emailed in a professional format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've never tried it but I read great things about Pentaho. Take a look at it.

http://www.pentaho.com/

Comment: This should've been a comment.